# ER-Diagram and SQL DDL for a library database

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

I'm trying to draw an ER-diagram and SQL ddl for a simple library database.

I have the following entities:

```
Book (holds the ISBN as key, book title, author)
Copy (copyID of a copy of a book, dateAcquired, dateDestroyed)
Member (MemberID, name, address)
Loaned (i guess the date due and the date back and obviously foreign keys for memberID and copyID)
```

Also a Member can be **Student** or **Staff**. So i think this should be a "IS-A" relationship.

How can i represent this in a proper ER-Diagram and SQL-DDL

Answer (score 1):

I used SQL Server 2008 Express to create this diagram for the Northwind db. The diagram was drawn by SSMS 
[image]

1. follow these steps
2. Expand the database in SSMS
3. Right click on Database Diagrams
4. Select New Databse Diagram
5. Select you tables in the Add Table dialog
   The diagram will be created and displayed in the window.  New tables, relationships, index etc may be created within the diagram window.

For the SQL-DDL I script the dataabse using SSMS